# Как в RecyclerView.Adapter узнать текущую view?

Tags: android

Как узнать и найти view текущую view в RecyclerView.Adapter??

Comment: что имеется в виду по текущей view?

Comment: У меня в RecyclerView.Adapter добавлено несколько RecyclerView.ViewHolder, как получить текущий?

Comment: текущий элемент списка?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, Да

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28304517/4829111 вот тут гляньте

Comment: у RecyclerView.ViewHolder есть метод getAdapterPosition который возвращает позицию. Соответственно можно её получить в адаптере: int position = getAdapterPosition();

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас есть адаптер для вашего списка, то там должна быть функция `onBindViewHolder` у меня эта функция выглядит так:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MainAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        viewHolder.tvSpecies.setText(alName.get(position));
        viewHolder.imgThumbnail.setImageResource(alImage.get(position));


        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int k = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

                }
            }
        });
    }
```

и вот класс в этом же адаптере:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        ImageView imgThumbnail;
        TextView tvSpecies;
        ItemClickListener clickListener;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imgThumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgActivity);
            tvSpecies = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            clickListener.onClick(view, getPosition(), false);
        }

    }
```

все элементы в это классе мои, но суть должна быть понятна. Если возникнут вопросы или затруднения, то не стесняйтесь и пишите, помогу чем смогу. Удачи :)

Comment: Круто. Но это при нажатии. А вот если просто мне нужно получить позицию программно, то как?

Comment: не очень понимаю если честно, ведь список используют для управления элементами списка, что вы имеете в виду под программным получением позиции?

Comment: Мне нужно получить определенный ViewHolder который сейчас "выбран". Если я могу указать позицию для скролла, то почему я сейчас не могу узнать выбранную позицию

Comment: тогда вам нужно заставить программу думать что вы нажали на элемент, введите переменную которая будет отвечать за нужную вам позицию, и дальше делайте выбор пункта меню который отвечает этой переменной